# issues filtering react JSX State array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a state array using useState that keeps track of some components, I add components to the array with a click of a button i.e

```
const [answerLines, setAnswerLines] = useState<any[]>([]);
```

adding to the array

```
const addAnswerLine = () => {
  setAnswerLines([
    ...answerLines,
    <NewTestAnswerLine
      key={answerLines.length}
      lineIndex={answerLines.length}
      isCorrect={answerLines.length === correctAnswer}
      setCorrectAnswer={setCorrectAnswer}
      deleteLine={() => deleteAnswerLine(answerLines.length)}
    />,
  ]);
};
```

when it comes deleting the lines by filtering out the array of the clicked line Id, it doesn't work as expected, for instance if I click the 0 index item the array filters to null.

This is my delete function that I pass down through props:

```
const deleteAnswerLine = (index: number) => {
  setAnswerLines(answerLines.filter((item) => item.props.lineIndex !== index));
};
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend storing _data_ in the array, then rendering _elements_ becomes a simple `answerLines.map((data) => <Component {/* use data*/} />)`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe , thank you! that actually makes so much sense and its easier to manage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following the advice from comments and changing tactic, saving the data on the state and using the state to map the array to components for display, this made it easier to manage and now the above functions work as intended.

example:

```
const [answerLines, setAnswerLines] = useState<object[]>([{
        id:0,
        answerText:"text answer 1",
        isCorrect:false

    },
    {
        id:1,
        answerText:"text answer 2",
        isCorrect:false

    }
```

function passed as props for deleting

```
const deleteAnswerLine = (index: number) => {
        setAnswerLines(answerLines.filter((item) => item.id !== index));
      };
```

displaying the data as components

```
 {answerLines.map(item=><NewTestAnswerLine isCorrect={item.id===correctAnswer}  setCorrectAnswer={setCorrectAnswer} lineIndex={item.id} key={item.id} deleteLine={()=>deleteAnswerLine(item.id)}/>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor the `deleteAnswerLine` function and use the callback version of the state setter to avoid [stale state](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-every-react-developer-should-know-about-state/#5-stale-state-can-happen-with-closures):

From:

```
const deleteAnswerLine = (index: number) => {
  setAnswerLines(answerLines.filter((item) => item.props.lineIndex !== index));
};
```

To:

```
  const deleteAnswerLine = (index: number) => {
    setAnswerLines(answerLines => answerLines.filter((item) => item.props.lineIndex !== index));
  };
```

[References](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)